# Inserting entries only once

Tags: sql

I have a relationships table, the table looks something like this

```
 ------------------------
| client_id | service_id |
 ------------------------
| 1         | 1          |
| 1         | 2          |
| 1         | 4          |
| 1         | 7          |
| 2         | 1          |
| 2         | 5          |
 ------------------------
```

I have a list of new permissions I need to add, what I'm doing right now is, for example, if I have to add new permissions for the client with id 1, i do

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE client_id = 1
INSERT INTO ....
```

Is there a more efficient way I can remove only the ones I won't insert later, and add only the new ones?

Comment: You're deleting by primary key, which will be so fast anyways, I honestly wouldn't worry about it.

Otherwise you'd have to put together a list of the service_id's you're inserting and include those as a where condition to your delete, something like this:

DELETE FROM myTable WHERE client_id = @myId AND service_id NOT IN (@serviceIds)

And that may take more memory/time than just doing the delete.

Comment: @robertvoliva: Lookups on primary keys are very fast, but deleting items may not be. The db server tries to keep the whole table arranged in order based on the primary key. When you delete items, the database has to determine whether it needs to restructure how it's storing the data. Sort of like taking a bunch of books off the shelf: at some point the librarian has to take time to shift all the books around so you don't end up with mostly-empty shelves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can do this but in my humble opinion, it's not really `sql` dependent subject. actually it depends on your language/platform choice. if you use a powerful platform like `.NET` or `Java`, there are many database classes like `adapters`, `datasets` etc. which are able to take care of things for you like finding the changed parts, updating/inserting/deleting only necessery parts etc.

i prefer using `hibernate`/`nhibernate` like libraries. in this case, you don't even need to write sql queries most of the time. just do the things at oop level and synchronize with the database.

Comment: I'm using .NET, how can DataSets help me in this situtation?

Comment: If you use DataSets with DataAdapters, DataAdapters will help you to achieve your goal. read this page carefully, specially the second paragraph. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you put the new permissions into another table, you could do something like:

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE client_id in (SELECT client_id FROM tmpTable);

INSERT INTO myTable AS (SELECT client_id, service_id FROM tmpTable);
```

You are still taking 2 passes, but you are doing them all at once instead of one at a time.